# ajax error on current page when redirecting to another page in jsf application

Tags: ajax, jsf, redirect, popup

I'm using the following code to redirect to another page,

```
<p:commandButton value="myRedirectButton" value="#{myBean.val}" rendered="#{myBean.renderThis}" 
onclick="remoteRedirect();"/>

<p:remoteCommand name="remoteRedirect" actionListener="#{myBean.redirectToPage}"/>
```

And the actionListener in java is as follows:

```
public static void redirectToPage(String url){
    FacesContext ctx= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ext=ctx.getExternalContext();
    String encodedUrl=ext.encodeRedirectUrl(ctx.getApplication().
                      getViewHandler.getActionUrl(ctx,url),
                      new HashMap<String,List<String>>());

    ext.redirect(encodedUrl);
```

}

On clicking the 'myRedirectButton', a js error pops up just before the page redirects saying

"**This message is only sent, because project stage is development and no other error listeners are registered**".

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

> This message is only sent, because project stage is development and no other error listeners are registered

This will show up when you're using MyFaces, and you have `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` set to `Development` in `web.xml`, and you don't have any `jsf.ajax.addOnError` listener, and the current request is an Ajax request, and the JS code has thrown an error during that request.

Basically, it's just trying to tell you that you should look in the JS console for the actual error, and/or that you should configure a `jsf.ajax.addOnError` for more fine grained JS error handling. Once having the detail about the actual JS error, you can easily naildown the cause and solve the problem.

As to the concrete problem, you're basically sending multiple ajax requests at the same time on click of the `<p:commandButton>`, first one via `<p:remoteCommand>` and immediately thereafter second one via `<p:commandButton>`. The first one will perform a redirect and hereby unexpectedly abort the second one before its response can be processed, hereby causing a JS error.

There are basically 2 ways to solve your timing problem:

1. Move the `action` from the `<p:remoteCommand>` to the `<p:commandButton>` and then remove the `onclick` and `<p:remoteCommand>` altogether.
2. Add a `return false;` in the end of the `onclick` to block the `<p:commandButton>` from sending its own ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. There is no exception/error in the logs. Also, this is only occurring in the scenarios wherein I'm redirecting out of the current page or refreshing the same page. The error  occurs on Firefox but not on IE-10 when running in Development/SystemTest mode.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to solve this in case onclick is not in-line and called from jquery on myRedirectButton. It is being called from jquery due to some conditional redirection logic at client-side Should I edit my original question.? Thanks for your proactive support to the jsf coders like myself :)